# Google Apps Email Bounces for few uses

Tags: email, google-workspace

I have two domains Google Apps (for argument sake - a.com and b.com).

I have setup the mx records according to what Google recommended for both the domains.

I receive all emails on a.com and mostly all on b.com. I mention mostly as I have few set of users who complain that they get a message from mailer-daemon

This is the email they forwarded (they are using exchange IMO) to my a.com domain telling that their email to my other domain are not going through. This tells me that it may not be Google apps.

I see that their SMTP server is trying to deliver this message to itservicecompany.com - I am not sure who their are - they are not senders.

```
From: MAILER-DAEMON
Sent: Wednesday, December 04, 2013 7:51 PM
To: user@b.com
Subject: Undeliverable: xxxx

Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

user@b.com
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.
The following organization rejected your message: mx1.emailsrvr.com.

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com
user@b.com
mx1.emailsrvr.com #<mx1.emailsrvr.com #5.7.1 smtp; 550 5.7.1 <user@itservicecompany.com>: Relay access denied.> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

Return-Path: <xxx.com>
Received: from smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id 7228E1C8265
    for <**user@itservicecompany.com>**; Wed,  4 Dec 2013 22:51:49 -0500 (EST)
X-SMTPDoctor-Processed: csmtpprox 2.7.4
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id 6BF681C828B
    for <**user@b.com**>; Wed,  4 Dec 2013 22:51:49 -0500 (EST)
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
Received: from smtp192.mex05.mlsrvr.com (unknown [184.106.31.85])
    by smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTPS id 54E1C1C8265
    for <**user@b.com**>; Wed,  4 Dec 2013 22:51:49 -0500 (EST)
Received: from ORD2MBX02D.mex05.mlsrvr.com ([fe80::92e2:baff:fe0f:a9d0]) by
 ORD2HUB08.mex05.mlsrvr.com ([fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe7f:6605%15]) with mapi id
 14.03.0158.001; Wed, 4 Dec 2013 21:51:49 -0600
```

Comment: This question does not belong on SU.  Recommend moving it to ServerFault.

Comment: Looks like you moved the Email from other provider to Google Apps, just double check that the user is in fact using Google Apps and not your previously setup Mail Server. Since there are none of the Gmail IPs or Domains in the email that you posted.

Comment: We have moved to Google Apps for more than a year now. It's not just with one user - it happens with all of them (very randomly - one in few hundreds). The same email goes to another domain which is hosted on Google Apps too. All MX records point to Google Apps recommended records. I am a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0):

From the header shown by you :

```
Received: from smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by smtp23.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id 7228E1C8265
    for <**user@itservicecompany.com>**; Wed,  4 Dec 2013 22:51:49 -0500 (EST)
```

So the server is using localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) instead of the actual IP address of the server hostname. This is the reason for the Email rejection.

To understand this please check [SMTP error codes](http://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide/error-codes)

Comment: Any idea on why it would use localhost instead of the actual IP? Is it the fault of the server at the sender's end?